# Regexp_Like to Validate Uppercase Characters [A-Z] and Numbers [0-9] Only

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-like

I would like a query using `regexp_like` within Oracle's SQL  which only validates uppercase characters **[A-Z]** and numbers **[0-9]**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM dual 
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('AAAA1111', '[A-Z, 0-9]')
```

Answer (score 2):

1. List item

The select Statement probalby should look like

```
SELECT 'Yes' as MATCHING 
  FROM dual 
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE ('AAAA1111', '^[A-Z0-9]+$')
```

Which means that starting from the very first ^ to the last $ letter every character should be upper case or a number. Important: no comma or space between Z and 0. The `+` stands for at least one or more characters.

Edit: Based on the answer of Barbaros another way of selecting would be possible

```
SELECT 'Yes' as MATCHING
  FROM DUAL 
 WHERE regexp_like('AAAA1111','^[[:digit:][:upper:]]+$')
```

Edit: added a [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4307dfd8f1de03a50306a0d92f5a7db0)

A quick help may be found [here](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-string-functions/oracle-regexp_like/) and for oracle regular expressions [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_regexp.htm).

Comment: no it is correct - you can try it on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4307dfd8f1de03a50306a0d92f5a7db0) - of course you'd need to select a column and not from dual, but otherwise its fine.

Comment: OK, you're right, you also considered the cases without space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
select str as "Result String" 
  from tab
 where not regexp_like(str,'[[:lower:] ]') 
   and regexp_like(str,'[[:alnum:]]')
```

where `not regexp_like` with *POSIX* `[^[:lower:]]` pattern stands for eliminating the strings
 containing lowercase,

and `regexp_like` with *POSIX* `[[:alnum:]]` pattern stands for accepting the strings
 without symbols

( *containing only letters and numbers **even doesn't contain a space** because of the trailing space at the end part of `[[:lower:] ]`* )

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b4212f277b1d75acca4027a437632037)</kbd>

Comment: Also a nice solution to use POSIX. I'd recommend for that solution to change the where condition to `where regexp_like(str,'[[:alnum:][:upper:]]')`. Strangely you'd still need a `[^[:space:]]` in order to avoid the spaces.

Comment: thank you @edi . I already tried that but gives wrong result ( aside for space consideration also ).

Comment: [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dc9b08fd090f29bdfb15661a1fe9f593) I've build on your solution which works without spaces and looks like `where regexp_like(str,'^[[:alnum:][:upper:]]+$')`

Comment: Unfortunately @edi , it still brings `EdUARDOFERRREIRA`, which contains lower-case letter , at least.

Comment: Yes, u're right :) - post to quickly... but ... this should do the trick `where regexp_like(str,'^[[:digit:][:upper:]]+$')` .... and the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9c11b713158e592f0cd76e8d04d1b88f).